# How to update all children records of an hierarchical data structure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have categories and groupings stored in an hierarchical order in a database. Each category may have another categories and groupings as it's children. So whenever I move a grouping to under another category or groupings it's category id will be updated and all it's children grouping's category id also should get updated.

The GROUPING table has the data as follows:

[image]

So, if I move grouping id 81 to a new category id 739720 then I want all children grouping's category id also to be updated to 739720.

in other words, I want to select all children records of a grouping in an hierarchical data structure and update their category ids.

I want data to be like below after the UPDATE.

[image]

Comment: May I be the first to point out that if the data model was properly normalised you wouldn't need to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO GROUPING dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID  AS rid
  FROM   GROUPING
  START WITH grouping_id = 81
  CONNECT BY PRIOR grouping_id = parent_id
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET CATEGORY_ID = 739720;
```

Comment: can this be achieved with CONNECT BY

Comment: 739720 is not grouping id, it is a category id. I just want to update the category id of children, not grouping id or parent id.

Comment: @user1614862 Updated

Comment: I am just trying to do like this:  which query is more efficient??
 
UPDATE grouping g1 
SET    g1.category_id = 739720 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT g2.grouping_id 
               FROM   grouping g2 
               WHERE  g2.grouping_id <> 81 
               START WITH g2.grouping_id = 81 
               CONNECT BY g2.parent_id = PRIOR g2.grouping_id)